# Is there any way to know the waitTime if Google calendar usageLimit or rateLimit is reached

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working on developing integration with Google Calendar using Rest API. I got to know Google applies both rateLimit and usageLimit on API calls - [403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded)

In case I breach the limits, I want to wait for a defined period of time before I retry the request again. Is there any way to know if there is something like `Retry-After` header returned by Google.

I checked documentation but not able to find anything related - [errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your quota in google developer console under libary search for google calendar and then click the manage button.   Under the quota tab you will see something like this.

[image]

There are two types of quota user based quota denoted by the "per user" and project based quotas.

Each user running my application can make a max of 600 requests per minute.   if they make to many then i will get a quota exception.

My application can make a max of 10000 request per minute in total.  if it makes more then that then again i will get a quota exception.

You may want to read though [Manage quotas](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/quota) this explains a lot about quota usage and the google calendar api.

For the most part if you just implement exponential backoff you should be able to avoid to many of these errors.

1. try request if fails
2. wait 10 seconds
3. try again if fails
4. wait 20 seconds
5. try again if fails
6. wait 30 seconds
7. try again
   .......

Comment: thanks. this is helpful. I was actually looking for some kind of `retry-after` header which could tell me the time I need to wait before retrying.

Comment: oh no this is all on you my friend.  We have not yet reached the point where the system's we are calling will do more than just responded to our requests.   Technically I would bet that the quote error is handled by a load balancing system of some kind its just going to kick it back

Comment: Welcome to stack remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will also improve your reputation